# converting a signal back and forth with trigonometric functions

Tags: matlab, octave, linear-algebra, trigonometry, algebra

I'm trying to convert a signal back and forth using trigonometric functions. In the example below:

- 1) start off with a cos signal
- 2) convert the signal to a secant signal
- 3) would like to convert the secant signal back to the
  original cosine signal. (Is this possible)

I know sec=1/cos I was trying to see if simple algebra would get the original signal back but it looks like my understanding of Trig is lacking, as you can see in the third plot below it doesn't go back to the original cos signal which is what I'm trying to do.

And please don't post just use **cos (x)** This is a simple example showing what I'm trying to do, the real code is about 500 lines with multiple functions that it calls.  I'm trying to see if there is a way to get back to the original signal using Trig and matlab/octave

Here's the example matlab / octave code below:

```
clear all, clf
x = linspace(0,2*pi,1000);
y = cos(x); % 
subplot(3,1,1); 
plot(x,y)
title('original signal')

y2 =1./cos(x);  % secant
subplot(3,1,2); 
plot(x,y2)
title('converted signal')

y3 =sec(y2).*sec(y2);  % this section is incorrect not sure how to fix it
subplot(3,1,3); 
plot(x,y3)
title('back to original cos signal from secant')
```

[image]

Comment: What's the purpose of `y3 =sec(y2).*sec(y2);`? When do you convert back to cos?

Comment: @Luis Mendo I was taking a shot in the dark to see if that would convert it back to the original cos signal, which of course it doesn't.  It's showing my lack of Trig understanding

Comment: I mean, why not `y3 = 1./y2;`? sec is 1/cos

Comment: @Luis Mendo thanks that will do it but I need to use a Trig function to get back to the original signal.

Answer (score 0):

Your `y3` calculation is incorrect:

`sec(y2) = 1/cos(y2) = 1/cos(1/cos(x))`

`y3  = sec(y2) * sec(y2) = 1 / cos(1/cos(x))^2`.

This is not equal to `cos(x)`, so there's no reason for `y3` to look like `y` in any way.

Comment: so is there a way to fix my y3 calculation?